# How can I create a custom firefox profile on a centos vm

Tags: selenium, firefox, centos7, firefox-profile

I have created a centos vm. Installed maven, firefox on it and placed selenium automation code to test my web application on it. The only issue is my automation code works on a specific profile where I need to enable the 'Open new windows in a new tab instead' firefox setting.

How can I create a custom firefox profile including this setting on a vm ?

I did a ssh on my vm and then did

```
firefox -CreateProfile Selenium
```

I cant find on which location this profile is created. Also I still could not figure out how to add custom settings, as the above just creates a profile I guess.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description on how to create (and move and remove) [Firefox profiles using the built-in Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). On linux it is usually located in `$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/`. Profile names are mapped to directories in `profiles.ini`

A custom profile can be used both programmatically (using FirefoxProfile, FirefoxOptions, [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html)) or [by command line parameter](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver).

Comment: I just noticed that 'firefox -CreateProfile Selenium' did not create a profile in my profiles.ini. also, the link you shared is for a browser that has UI. My browser is installed on a no ui VM. Can you please help me with creating a profile for firefox browser that does not have a UI?

Comment: The description contains information about how to _move_ a profile as well. So you could create one on a VM with GUI and move it to the test environment. Also, you can configure a FirefoxProfile programmatically. see the links provided.